# Implementing __next__ in a custom class

Tags: python, class

I have a class that looks like this

```
Class myClass:

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
```

where `key` is a string and `value` is always a list of elements of myClass, possibly empty.

I want to define my own iter method that returns `value.key` for each `value` in `values`. I tried

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self 

def __next__(self):
    try:
        self.value.next().key
    except:
        raise StopIteration
```

but it's looping forever. What am I doing wrong?
Also if I want to have Python 2 / 3 compatibility, should I add the method

```
def next(self):
    return self.__next__()
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `def __iter__(self): return iter(self.value)`?

Comment: as far as compatibility goes yes, you can also just use `next(self..)`.  What exactly do you want to do? What is `self.value.next().key` supposed to do?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This was my first try, but then I will lose the possibility of defining my own `__next__` that i need in order to extract the `key` from values

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am writing this in a package, and I need to be able to use it both with P3 and P2

Comment: I am not sure I fully get what `self.value.next().key` is supposed to do

Comment: @PadraicCunningha m you are right; `values` is a list of elements of `myClass`. I edited to explain it better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason for you to implement `__next__`. You can use `__iter__` to return a generator which will do what you want.

```
class Pair(object):

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

    def __iter__(self):
        return (v.key for v in self.value)

    # alternative iter function, that allows more complicated logic
    def __iter__(self):
        for v in self.value:
             yield v.key

p = Pair("parent", [Pair("child0", "value0"), Pair("child1", "value1")])

assert list(p) == ["child0", "child1"]
```

This way of doing things is compatible with both python2 and python3 as the returned generator will have the required `next` function in python2, and `__next__` in python3.

Answer (score 3):

You need to extract and preserve an **iterator** on list `self.value` -- you can't just call `next` on a list, you need an iterator on such a list.

So, you need an auxiliary iterator class:

```
class myClassIter(object):

    def __init__(self, theiter):
        self.theiter = theiter

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.theiter).key

    next = __next__
```

which I've also made Py 2/3 compatible with the `object` base and appropriate aliasing.

Here, I'm assuming every item in the list has a `key` attribute (so the only expected exception is `StopIteration`, which you can just propagate).  If that is not the case, and you want to just stop the iteration when an item is met without the attribite, the `try`/`except` is needed, but **keep it tight!** -- a crucial design aspect of good exception handling.  I.e, if these are indeed your specs:

```
    def __next__(self):
        try: return next(self.theiter).key
        except AttributeError: raise StopIteration
```

don't catch **all** exceptions -- only the ones you specifically expect!

Now, in `myClass`, you'll want:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return myClassIter(iter(self.value))
```

This means that `myClass` is an **iterable**, not an **iterator**, so you can e.g properly have more than one loop on a `myClass` instance:

```
mc = myClass(somekey, funkylist)
for ka in mc:
    for kb in mc:
        whatever(ka, kb)
```

If `mc` was itself an iterator, the inner loop would exhaust it and the semantics of the nested loops would therefore be completely different.

If you do indeed want such completely different semantics (i.e you **want** `mc` to be itself an iterator, not just an iterable) then you must dispense with the auxiliary class (but still need to store the iterator on `self.value` as an instance attribute for `myClass`) -- that would be a strange, uncomfortable arrangement, but it **is** (just barely) possible that it is indeed the arrangement your application needs...